# Obtaining a number between current date and event date in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am currently developing a daily safety report. I would like to write a formula to count injury free days if a certain condition is met. If the value in the **Injury type Field** is "Lost Time Injury" it should take the date from the **Date Field** and count the difference between the current date and time as a number.

Answer (score 1):

```
If Not(Isnull({table.injuryType})) And {table.injuryType}="Lost Time Injury" Then
  CurrentDate - {table.dateField}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a group to your report, with the Month parameter of your report.
and write a formula like this and add it to your header

```
if(certain check about injuries != null) then
(
    no injuries
)
else
(
    injuries++;
)

injuries;
```

hope it helps